# VisualVM is stopped by Cylance protect antivirus

Tags: eclipse, java-11, antivirus, visualvm

By enterprise policy, we have to run Cylance protect antivirus on our workstations. It cannot be suspended or uninstalled.
I can start VisualVM, but when I try to connect to a process, a message is displayed by Cylance protect that the process of VisualVM was stopped because it was "recognized as a threat".
*Edit: I see VisualVM's start page where the Java processes, including VisualVM and Eclipse, are displayed. As soon as I select a process and try any action (monitor, profile, etc.) Cylance pops up and hard terminates VisualVM. The Java processes keep running.*
The tech team thinks this comes from VisualVM trying to access another process' memory.

My system: Java 11, Eclipse 2022-12, Windows 11.

We tested for a short time with Cylance disabled and then the profiling worked.
(I needed some time to talk my tech team into that so this does not seem to be a practicable solution.)
I don't expect this to change with the Java or Eclipse version. Was already the same with Java 8 and / or elder Eclipse versions.
Has anybody the same constellation and knows how to configure a rule in Cylance that profiling with VisualVM is possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is absolutely no code to provide, bot.

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly does not work. Do you see java application in VisualVM? Can you open it and see Overview/Monitoring/etc. I am not sure what Eclipse has to do with it.